# solving differential equations of the type $x\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}+\frac{dx}{dt}=0$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

What is the method for solving these types of differential equations:

$$x\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}+\frac{dx}{dt}=0$$

Comment: @ShuhaoCao $(xx')' = (x')^2 + xx''$

Comment: @Kaster Thanks for correcting my mistake, maybe I am too accustomed to using $x$ as the independent variables.

Comment: Is it minus or plus in the equation?  I changed it to minus in my answer.

Comment: it actually was plus sorry

Comment: No problem - the technique did not depend on the sign of $\dot{x}$ in the equation.

Answer (score 1):

The method below relies on changing the dependent variable form $x$ to its derivative, and the independent variable from $t$ to $x$.  This is common in phase-space techniques, and uses the chain rule.  Start by using the fact that

$$\frac{d}{dt}(x \dot{x})= \dot{x}^2+x \ddot{x}$$

where $\dot{x} = dx/dt$, etc.  Then

$$x \ddot{x} + \dot{x} = 0 \implies \frac{d}{dt}(x \dot{x}) = \dot{x}^2-\dot{x}$$

Dividing both sides by $\dot{x}$, we get

$$\frac{d(x \dot{x})/dt}{dx/dt} = \frac{d(x \dot{x})}{dx} = \dot{x}-1 $$

or

$$x \frac{d \dot{x}}{dx} = -1$$

The solution to this equation is

$$\dot{x} = -\log{x}+C$$

where $C$ is a constant of integration.  We may then solve this diff eq'n to get

$$t+C' = \int \frac{dx}{C-\log{x}} = -e^{C} \,\text{Ei}(\log{x}-C)$$

This is about as far as I will take this.

Comment: sorry was wondering how $x\ddot{x}+\dot{x}=0$

Comment: @romama: this is your equation, the one you posted and seek to solve.  I just used the dots to simplify the notation for my latter steps.

Comment: (+1) for the work of course Ron ! @romama: don't hope something much simpler : the same result with $t$ in function of $x$ is proposed by [EqWorld](http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/ode/ode0321.pdf) and [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%28x%28t%29*x%27%27%28t%29%2bx%27%28t%29=0,x%28t%29%29) (except the exponential that seems to be $-e^C$).

Comment: @RaymondManzoni: thanks, man, much appreciated as always.